# Remove row from two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to remove a row from 2 dimensional arrays. But I didn't find something useful searching google, every thing I find is about remove from `ArrayList`.

This is my 2 dimensional array :

```
int[][] Dirt = {{4, 2}, {0, 5}, {7, 1}, {3, 3}};
```

and for example I want to remove {0,5}
here it must remove the row from the Dirt .

```
for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
    if(pos[0]==Dirt[z][0]&& pos[1]==Dirt[z][1]){
        System.out.println("Dirt[z][0]"+Dirt[z][0] +"Dirt[z][1]"+Dirt[z][1]);
        //here it must remove the row from the Dirt 
    }
}
```

Any suggestion ?

---

I tried to copry the arryay to new one,, But also not work

this is the output:

> > [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] [
> >     ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][
> >     ] [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][
> >     ][ ][ ]
>
> choise taste equal5:4 5:4 nowX and nowY   at test.Move(test.java:121)
>     at test.main(test.java:149) Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total
>   time: 3 seconds)

and This my code:

```
int[][] Dirt = {{4, 2}, {0, 5}, {7, 1}, {3, 3}};
int[][] temp = Dirt;
int size = Dirt.length - 1;


public void Move() {
    Collections.shuffle(orientation);
    int nowX = 4, nowY = 4;           
    int counter = 0;
    int strightCounter = 1;
    Dirt = new int[size][2];
    int newIndex = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    while (!(Dirt.length == 0)) {


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            choices.add(orientation.get(i));

            board[nowX][nowY] = "1";
            int[] pos = gostright(nowX, nowY);
            nowX = pos[0];
            nowY = pos[1];
            System.out.println("" + nowX + ":" + nowY);
            System.out.println("nowX and nowY" + board[nowX][nowY]);
            board[nowX][nowY] = "#";
            moves++;
            for (int z = 0; z < temp.length; z++) {
                int[] oneDimension = temp[z];
                if (pos[0] == oneDimension[0] && pos[1] == oneDimension[1]) {
                             continue;
                }else{           
                    Dirt[newIndex][0] = oneDimension[0];
                    Dirt[newIndex][1] = oneDimension[1];
                    newIndex++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The array After removing : ");
            for (int s = 0; s < Dirt.length; s++) {
                System.out.println(Dirt[s][0] + "," + Dirt[s][1]);
            }

            System.out.println(toString());
            System.out.println(orientation.get(i));
            System.out.println("Choices " + choices);
            System.out.println("# move" + moves);
            if (Wall(nowX, nowY)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        counter++;

    }
}


any suggestion ??
```

Comment: I tried to this one : But also give an error:

Answer (score 2):

In Java arrays are static in size, meaning that you cannot change the size of the array once it has been created. That is the reason you have only found answers relating to ArrayLists.

Comment: to accomplish this functionality you can create a new array with size = size -1 and then copy the relevant values (minus the deleted row) into the new array. Then reassign the old array to refer to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't change the size of an array, perhaps it would be better if you create another array and only insert the elements you need

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve something that's impossible.

Arrays are fixed so once created you can not modify their size.

You can create that effect of removing a row by creating a new array with one less row dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to *replace* the array with a new one. Here's 4 lines that will do it:

```
// original array
int[][] dirt = { { 4, 2 }, { 0, 5 }, { 7, 1 }, { 3, 3 } };
int z = 1; // the element to remove

// create a new smaller array
int[][] dirt2 = new int[dirt.length - 1][];
// copy everything from 0 to z
System.arraycopy(dirt, 0, dirt2, 0, z);
// copy from z+1 to end
System.arraycopy(dirt, z + 1, dirt2, z, dirt.length - z - 1);
// reassign
dirt = dirt2;
```

Comment: I tried this,, but didn't work ,, give this error:            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Comment: @ElfagerElbeaeed The code is perfect - I tested it with all valid values (in this example, in the range 0 to 3 inclusive) and it worked as expected. You could only get that exception by using a value of `z` that is outside the array - in this example, the array has 4 elements, so that largest valid value of `z` is `3`, so if you used `4` (or larger), you would get that error. Check your usage of this code.

Answer (score -1):

<del>Java array is immutable object.</del> 
You want to remove or to add items, you have to regenerate array object. If adding and removing items flexibly, I also suggest to use Collection Objects such as ArrayList , HashMap and etc.

Comment: Java arrays are not immutable. This size and type are fixed, but the contents are fully mutable. Agree with your advice about using other collections if you want more flexibility of course :-)

Comment: thanks mikera. I cunfused with String class. of course, array's contents are fully mutable, but String is not. ^^.